# Uploaded ASP.NET web application does not send email

Tags: asp.net, email

I am developing a web application, which is planned to send confirmation emails to new members. I am new to email service development with ASPET. The app runs without error or exception, and apparently sends emails as the try and catch blocks return ano exception. However, no one receives even a mail. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public void SendEmailAddressVerificationEmail(string Username, string To)
    {
        MEFManager.Compose(this);
        string encryptedName = Username.Encrypt("verify");

        string msg = "Please click on the link below or paste it into a browser to verify your email account.<BR><BR>" +
                        "<a href=\"" + _configuration.RootURL + "Account/VerifyEmail.aspx?a=" +
                        encryptedName + "\">" +
                        _configuration.RootURL + "Account/VerifyEmail.aspx?a=" +
                        encryptedName + "</a>";

        SendEmail(To, "", "", "Account created! Email verification required.", msg);
    }


public void SendEmail(string To, string CC, string BCC, string Subject, string Message)
    {
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS,To);
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CC))
            mm.CC.Add(CC);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BCC))
            mm.Bcc.Add(BCC);

        mm.Subject = Subject;
        mm.Body = Message;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

        Send(mm);
    }


private void Send(MailMessage Message)
    {
        try
        {
        //During developement we will not be sending mails
#if !DEBUG
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Send(Message);
        Console.Write("E-mail sent!");
#endif

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Also the web.config and web.release.config files are as follows:

Web.config:

```
<system.net>
 <mailSettings>
  <smtp>
            <network host="localhost" port="25" defaultCredentials="true"/>
  </smtp>
 </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

web.release.config:

```
<smtp from="postmaster@itok.com">
  <network
      host="mail.itok.com"  
      defaultCredentials="true"
      enableSsl="false"             
      port="25"
      userName="postmaster@itok.com"
      password="*********"
      xdt:Transform="Replace"
    />
</smtp>
```

Can anybody help me to find the reason? Does anybody have an idea or suggestion where to look for an answer? What could be the sources of such problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer your question, but here are a few tips that are too long to put in a comment.

In your development environment, enable sending mails using delivery method `specifiedPickupDirectory`, rather than using conditional compilation to disable sending mails (`IF !DEBUG...`).

This will enable you to test your code in your development environment - just check that the email files are being created in the specified directory (which must exist and be writable by the web application).

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" from="postmaster@itok.com">
  <network host="localhost"/>
  <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Temp\mails\"/>
</smtp>
```

If it works in your development environment, you can then assume that your code is probably OK, and the problem is with the deployed configuration.

Your use of `Console.Write` to log errors in a web application looks suspicious: where are you expecting to see these errors?

Comment: Hi Joe, and thanks a million for the response. I have applied the changes, and now I can find emails in the C:\Temp\mails\ directory. So now I am sure that my code works perfectly (in producing link emails). Do you have any idea where to go from here to look for the solution of the problem? I have called the ISP guys, and they think the configuration is the one they have given me already!!!

Comment: @بابکخلیفهسلطان Next thing I'd try is to remove the try/catch block.  If there's a problem with your configuration, I'd expect an exception to be thrown, and I don't see how Console.Write will help you to see the exception details.

Comment: My problem is here. The code either doesn't throw any exception, or it throws but I cant detect it. But apparently everything seems OK. It gives the message that: "The mail has been sent"!!! Also the "Console.Write" was my mistake. I was testing something, and I forgot to remove it.